# Why disable object cloning in PHP?

Tags: php, clone

Over the years I have seen in various pieces of PHP code people who disable object cloning, either by making `__clone()` private or by making that method throw an exception.

I would like to know why people do this. Is it only when creating singleton objects, or are there other situations where this is good practice?

Thanks

Comment: Here is a free hint to improve your life: never use singletons.

Comment: Thanks @tereško I am aware of this and I dislike singletons myself as well. But for better or for worse, people do use them when developing WordPress plugins. They are simply a way to encapsulate your stuff in a namespace without using the PHP namespaces feature. Not everyone has upgraded to PHP 5.3 or later. Anyway my question is open-ended because I was hoping to learn more about PHP cloning and in particular if there are situations (frameworks?) where it can cause problems. Thanks.

Comment: In reasonably written code it *shouldn't* cause issues. The only exception I'd make to this is anything that acquires external *resources* (like database handles or open files), which may be troublesome if cloned. Other than that I can hardly think of a sane reason to do so.

Comment: @deceze Thanks that looks like a valid answer to my question that I had not thought about. You should write this as an answer so I (and others) can upvote it.